# If $(E,d)$ is a separable metric space and $X:\Omega\to E$ is measurable, then there are $X_n$ with $d(X,X_n)\to 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $(E,d)$ be a separable metric space and $E_0=(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ be a dense subset of $E$
- $X:\Omega\to E$ be $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(E)$-measurable, $$d_n:=\min_{1\le i\le n}d(X,e_i)$$ $$k_n:=\min\left\{i\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}:d_n=d(X,e_i)\right\}$$ and $$X_n:=e_{k_n}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Clearly, $d_n$ is $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(E)$-measurable, but why $X_n$ is $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(E)$-measurable too?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '$\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}(E)$-measurable'?

Comment: @rt6 $X^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal A$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(E)$, where $\mathcal B(E)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a composition of two measurable maps $k_n: \Omega \to \Bbb N$ and $e:\Bbb N \to E$.

The first map is $k_n:\Omega \to \Bbb N$ given by $k_n(\omega) = \min\{ 1 \leq i \leq n: d_n(\omega) = d(X(\omega),e_i) \}$. Here $\Bbb N$ is given the discrete sigma algebra, i.e. all sets are measurable. This map is measurable because $$k_n^{-1}(\{i\}) = \{d_n(\omega) = d(X(\omega),e_i)\}\cap  \bigcap_{j<i} \{d_n(\omega) \neq d(X(\omega),e_j)\}$$

and we know that the sets on the RHS are in $\cal A$, since $X$ is $(\mathcal A, \mathcal B(E))$-measurable.

The second map is $e: \Bbb N \to E$ given by $e(n):=e_n$, and this is measurable because all countable subsets (in particular, all subsets of $E_0$) are measurable in the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: And I guess you mean "in particular, all subsets of $E_0$".

Comment: Yes, thanks....